# use the same field definition in the different tables

Tags: liquibase

If I would like to use the same definition of the column in the different tables avoiding  mix like for example Customer ID NUMBER(9) , do I have built in ability to do it in respectively `Liquibase` or `FlyWayDB` ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [`parameters`](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changelog_parameters.html) does what you are looking for? You could define `NUMBER(9)` as a parameter for all you ID fields.